# Optimizing an iterative for loop for iOS app

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optimization, instruments

This may sound a little dumb question; but since I am new to programming, I thought some of you might be able to help me in this regard. I have the following snippet of code:

```
    for k in 0..<64{
        for i in 0..<14{
            for j in 0..<14{
                for di in 0..<5{
                    for dj in 0..<5{
                        for q in 0..<32{
                            A2[0][j][i][k] = A2[0][j][i][k] + T2[0][j+dj+1][i+di+1][q]*W2[k][q][dj][di]

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you can see that the for loop is running for 64*14*14*5*5*32 = 10035200 times. When I looked into the Instruments for performance, I found out that this portion of the code was taking 57.4% of the running performance time. I have posted a snapshot below.

[image: Performance Snapshot!]

Is there a way to optimize it? I thought of converting it into an one-dimensional array and do the calculation; but it will just make the code more confusing to follow in terms of readability.

EDIT:

```
 var A2: [[[[Float]]]] = [[[[Float]]]](count: 1, repeatedValue: [[[Float]]](count: 14, repeatedValue: [[Float]](count: 14, repeatedValue: [Float](count: 64, repeatedValue: Float()))))

 var T2: [[[[Float]]]] = [[[[Float]]]](count: 1, repeatedValue: [[[Float]]](count: 20, repeatedValue: [[Float]](count: 20, repeatedValue: [Float](count: 32, repeatedValue: Float()))))


    for k in 0..<32{
        for i in 0..<14{
            for j in 0..<14{
                T2[0][i+3][j+3][k] = HP1[0][i][j][k]
            }
        }
    }
```

HP1 is an array previously calculated; W2 is previously calculated and the above calculation is done accordingly.

Comment: Like the code isn't confusing already? First, can these calculations be done on a background thread? If so, dump the thing to a background thread and keep moving. If you absolutely MUST have to do this crazy thing and performance is top priority, then sacrifice the readability to make it as optimized as you can. Less loops is (normally) faster.

Comment: How would you possibly approach to optimize it?

Comment: Could you describe the problem, what exactly is being calculated here?

Comment: I have posted a little more detailed version of the code in the EDIT. I hope that helps.

Comment: I found I got a huge performance increase when using libdispatch's `dispatch_apple()`. It was on a Mac however.

Comment: How much was the performance increase and how did you use it?

Comment: Is the result always the same? Can you just hardcode the result into your app?

Comment: @AaronBrager I wish that was the case. The result changes in various cases.

Comment: @Mrwerdo I tried dispatch_apple() but I am getting  malloc_error_break error. Have you faced it before?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replay, I was on a camp with no reception :) I was making fractals on an iMac, so I'm not sure what performance increase you will get on iOS. I ran into memory issues too with swift arrays, I guessing it's to do with copying semantics. I used UnsafeMutablePointer to get around it as I was able to guarantee that two threads wouldn't write to the same location at once.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple start: You have three loops for i, j and k, and then you have three inner loops where you add things to the same element A2 [0][i][j][k]. So you take this:

```
for di in 0..<5{
    for dj in 0..<5{
        for q in 0..<32{
            A2[0][j][i][k] = A2[0][j][i][k] + T2[0][j+dj+1][i+di+1][q]*W2[k][q][dj][di]
         }
    }
}
```

and change it to:

```
let sum = A2[0][j][i][k]
for di in 0..<5{
    for dj in 0..<5{
        for q in 0..<32{
            sum += T2[0][j+dj+1][i+di+1][q]*W2[k][q][dj][di]
         }
    }
}
A2[0][j][i][k] = sum
```

Now I assume you do this more than once (since 10 million isn't that much), so maybe tell us how you call this multiple times - maybe that's where you can save something.

BTW. With that kind of problem you may find a *huge* difference between a debug build and a release build.

If you can rearrange the array W2 so that you can access it as W2[k][dj][di][q], that would likely help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this now. Yes, there is a difference between debug build and release build. Release build is slower than debug. Is that what is the case?

Comment: Release build should be faster. Are you compiling with `-OFast`?

Comment: Release build is slower? That's weird.

Comment: My bad. Release build is faster! However, there is a huge difference when I run the code in iPhone simulator and iPhone phone.